# Send CSV File To Elasticsearch With No Success Using Logstash

Tags: csv, file, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to use logstash for the first time, my goal is to send a csv file through the logstash to the elastic search and then use it in the kibana dashboards to show information.

My Operating System is Windows 10.

Kibana and elastic running fine.

When I try to run logstash it is running but stack on the "pipeline running" line like this:

[logstash run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkHHj.png)

And the file does not appear when I search with kibana's devTools when I type the GET command.

My configuration files for logstash is like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/TestsFinalProjectRuppin/Sample_Log_01_01_8_6.15.2021_15941_PM"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "Sample_Log_01_01_8_6.15.2021_15941_PM"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The stdout is used to see if it printing something to the console but again no success nothing but the "pipline running" line.

It is important to note that I tried to do as said in the tutorial of logstash in the elasticsearch site with no success.

Thanks in advance for all helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging of issue:
In output section remove elasticsearch section.. and keep only stdout and see if something comes up on console.
Also check the logstash log file.. if there is any error there
If yes then it can be index name issue.. try some simple index name first.

Comment: First of all thanks,
I tried but the console still showing the same screen as before even with only stdout,

I don't see any errors only warnings logstash folder I checked the folder logs and in it I checked the file logstash-deprecation.log:

```logstash-deprecation.log
[2021-06-16T18:22:16,030][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
```

Comment: have only warnings.. :\

Comment: Also check in elasticsearch if that index  Sample_Log_01_01_8_6.15.2021_15941_PM   is created. http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices. Your file It is in C drive so it can be a permission issue also

Comment: Not created. how can I solve this if it is a permission issue, move it the desktop?

Comment: Move it to another drive . D drive

Comment: Don't have another drive. 

but some how it works when the conf file like this with stdout instead of elasticsearch

```input {
 file {
  path => "C:/TestsFinalProjectRuppin/Sample_Log_01_01_8_6.15.2021_15941_PM.csv"
  start_position => "beginning"
  sincedb_path => "NULL"
 }
}
filter {
 csv {
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
  index => "Sample_Log_01_01_8_6.15.2021_15941_PM"
 }
}
```
but with the elasticsearch plugin it is not :\ it is the same as in the beginning

Comment: In short I meant it is working on the console but not with elasticsearch.

Comment: If you want to reread a file you need to set `sincedb_path` to `NUL` in windows, not `NULL`. Using `NULL`, with 2 `L`, you are saving the last position read to a file named `NULL` so when you try to read it again, it won't work as it was already read, setting to `NUL` will not save the last position read, so you will be able to reread the file.